# Change default application for .strm files but not other types of files?

Tags: file-format, file-type

I'm trying to get .strm files (live streaming text file with the link) to automatically play with VLC. I've obviously done the 'set to default' option when telling it to use VLC, but unfortunately it then changes other text based files e.g. .txt to open with VLC also. If I set .txt to open with Leafpad, then the .strm file also defaults to opening with Leafpad also. I'm using PcMANFm-QT 0.17.0.

Is there a way to add another specific filetype of .strm?

I'm using:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

Comment: I do not think you have a VLC issue. In case you do it may be better to ask in the VLC forum and not here.

Comment: @David I think it's a file manager / file type handling situation rather than VLC, I just couldn't do any other tags than VLC because I'm a new account